# While loop not executing and I don't know why

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm creating a loop and for some reason it doesn't execute. It's not an infinate loop

```
while ((aH <= 0) || (bH <= 0))
{
  // ROUND LOOP START
  System.out.println("============");
  System.out.println("  Round " + round);
  System.out.println("============");


  // A TURN START
  while (endTurn == 1)
  {
   System.out.println("==========================");
   System.out.println("  Commander " + aN + ", GO!");
   System.out.println("==========================");
   endTurn++;

  // A TURN END
  }
  endTurn--;


  // B TURN START
  while (endTurn == 1)
  {
    System.out.println("==========================");
   System.out.println("  Commander " + bN + ", GO!");
   System.out.println("==========================");
   endTurn++;

  // B TURN END
  }
  endTurn--;
  bH -= 10;

  round++;
  // ROUND LOOP END
}

System.out.println("The loop was skipped for some reason");
```

When I executed the test on the loop, this is what happened.

```
The loop was skipped for some reason
```

Currently the loop has no purpose, it will have functions, but I'm currently concerned with it not executing. Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: what are your variables being initialized to?

Comment: we have no idea what the values for `aH` or `bH` are to start with so we can't answer this. I predict they are greater than 0.

Comment: Your nested loops look odd as well. Let's take the first one. Assume endTurn==1. Then the loop will execute, endTurn will become 2 and the loop will exit. Else Assume that endTurn does not equal 1. Then the loop won't execute. Why not just use an if statement instead of the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slapped myself when I realized that I was using the while loop incorrectly. Anyway... not a problem anymore! Thanks anyways!